# How to create different user account types in ASP.NET5 MVC6 with Google+ authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, google-authentication

Suppose I started with an ASP.NET5 MVC6 webapp based on a default Visual Studio 2015 web application template with individual user accounts and Google+ (FB, LI) authentication enabled.

Then I created two signup pages, one for consumer users and one for professionals. I want the application to create consumer user accounts if users came from consumer signup page. And I want the app to create professional user accounts if users came from the professional signup page.

What should I do to customize the default solution?

- pass role parameter to /Accounts/ExternalLogin, then somehow preserve it through OAuth process and fix user creation logic?
- same but use cookies to pass role info?
- or maybe have 2 copies of external login infrastructure - each responsible for its own account type?

Isn't is a common problem - how to pass additional information to the code responsible for account creation?

Answer (score 0):

> What should I do to customize the default solution?

Quite good explanation with examples:
[ASP.NET 5 Documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) -> [Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/index.html)

> I want ... create consumer user accounts ... and ... create professional user accounts...

In my opinion you can use (create) one account type for all (in common Db) and then during registration process you can assign additional properties to this account. You can use Roles or Claims, so this allows you to personalise user experience depends on 'account type' (using Authorisation).

If you just want have only customer/professional accounts, probably [Role-Based Authorisation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/roles.html) will be simpler to use, however [Claims-Based Authorisation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html) is little bit more elastic and will be beneficial in the future.